# Ограничить вызов функций php

Tags: php

Проблема в следующем: для некоторого php скрипта нужно ограничить вызов некоторых функций, ну т.е. чтобы в нем нельзя было вызвать скажем функцию exec и т.д. Есть ли готовые решения позволяющие это сделать?

Comment: Создаете класс, устанавливаете приватные методы, работаете

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532987/disable-php-functions-within-htaccess

Comment: Не всё так просто. Есть класс в пределах которого человек может вызывать методы только этого класса, но он не должен вызывать функции не принадлежащие этому классу. Как вариант конечно можно пропарсить весь код и смотреть принадлежит ли та или иная функция данному классу или нет. Но хотелось бы решения попроще.

Answer (score 1):

Проверить принадлежит ли метод классу можно с помощью `method_exists`. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.method-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

Ограничивать использование php функций надо в php.ini

```
disable_functions = "show_source, system, shell_exec, exec"
```

Если требуется ограничить какие то функции для определенных скриптов, то лучше всего создать для них отдельный php.ini файл и VirtualHost, который будет работать с заданным php.ini.